# My add word to array if not in there already function is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, search, boolean, lookup

I have an array and am reading in a series of words from a text file. What I am trying to do is if the current word that the scanner is on is not in the array, then add it to the array. If the word is already in the array, then go to the next word and start the process again - check if its in the array, and if not add it, and so on. The problem is I load a word, abc, and it is not in the array so I add it. I then load another word, x, its not in the array so I add it. I then try to load abc again, and it is already in the array, but it gets added anyway. What needs to be changed in my code?

```
    try {
        fileScanner = new Scanner(inFile).useDelimiter("[ ,!?.0123456789]+");
        System.out.println("The input has been loaded successfully.");

        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            currentWord = fileScanner.next().toUpperCase();

            // If the word is not found, add it to the array.
            if (ht.findWord(currentWord, ht.array) == false) {
                ht.fillTable(currentWord, ht.asciiSum(currentWord), ht.array);
            } else {
            // if the word is found, move on to the next word.
                break;
            }

        }
        fileScanner.close();
    } // end try
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("The input file has not been successfully loaded.");
    }



public boolean findWord(String word, String[] table) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        if (table[i] == word) {
            found = true;
            //System.out.println("The word " + word + " was found at " + table[i]);
        } else {
            found = false;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: wrong way of comparing two string table[i] == word. you must use equals()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be changed a bit in the `findWord` method:

```
public boolean findWord(String word, String[] table) {
    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        if (table[i].equals(word)) {
            //this line is necessary because otherwise your loop
            //will continue setting found to false if there are
            //any other words in the array
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you want to compare two string you must use `equals()` funtion

**public boolean equals(Object anObject)**

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if
>   and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that
>   represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

```
if (table[i] == word) {
```

change to

```
if (table[i].equals(word)) {
```

As a result, `findWord(String word, String[] table) {` does not just return `false`.

Another point

```
 if (ht.findWord(currentWord, ht.array) == false) {
```

is equal

```
if (!ht.findWord(currentWord, ht.array)) {
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me all this information. It was very helpful.